# Error In Android - Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Recently I started developing android applications, when compiling the application in the emulator the process is terminated.

**LogCat:**

```
05-10 17:55:21.539: D/AndroidRuntime(4293): Shutting down VM
05-10 17:55:21.539: W/dalvikvm(4293): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020578)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{br.me.example.clientes/br.me.example.clientes.Principal}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.me.example.clientes.Principal in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/br.me.example.clientes-2.apk]
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.me.example.clientes.Principal in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/br.me.example.clientes-2.apk]
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
05-10 17:55:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4293):     ... 11 more
```

Class Principal

```html
package br.me.clientes;

import br.me.example.clientes.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Principal extends Activity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.principal);

  Button btnCadastro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCadastro);
  Button btnListar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnListar);
  Button btnApagar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnApagar);
  Button btnSair = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSair);

  btnCadastro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Cadastro.class));

   }
  });

  btnListar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Cadastro.class));

   }
  });

  btnApagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Cadastro.class));

   }
  });

  btnSair.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Cadastro.class));

   }
  });

 }

}
```

Class Cadastro

```html
package br.me.clientes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import br.me.example.clientes.R;

public class Cadastro extends Activity implements Runnable {

 private ProgressDialog pd;
 private String valor;
 private EditText txtNome;
 private EditText txtEmail;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.cadastro);

  Button btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
  txtNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
  txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
  final EditText txtEndereco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEndereco);
  final EditText txtNumero = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNumero);

  btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(Cadastro.this, "Aguarde",
      "Cadastrando informações", true, false);
    Thread t = new Thread(Cadastro.this);
    t.start();

   }
  });

 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  valor = txtNome.getText().toString();

  if (txtNome.getText().toString().equals(" ")) {
   h2.sendEmptyMessage(0);
  }

 }

 private Handler h = new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
   pd.dismiss();
   Toast t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), txtNome.getText(),
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
   t.show();

  }
 };

 private Handler h2 = new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
   pd.dismiss();
   Toast t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Preencha o campo Nome",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
   t.show();
   txtNome.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

  }
 };

}
```

Android Manifest

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.me.example.clientes"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity 
            android:name=".Principal">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"> </action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"> </category>    
        
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <activity android:name=".Cadastro"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Ready.

If you need something let me know.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you.

Comment: Please include your AndroidManifest.xml too. The log shows that the system is trying to load `br.me.example.clientes.Principal`, is there really an Activity with such  a name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in your package name.
In your `Manifest` you specify that your default package is `br.me.example.clientes`. 
You then specify your class by `.Principal`, it will search a class with the following path `br.me.example.clientes.Principal`.

But as we see in your class `Principal`, it his located here `br.me.clientes.Principal`.

Try to either fix the path in the `Manifest` or in the class.

Comment: Thanks everyone , it was a detail that made the difference.